# Refer to a large size matrix in previous time step

Tags: matlab, matrix, factorial

I want to create a time step and calculate the value of my parameter in next time step. But the problem is how I want to recall the previous/next time step when my matrix size parameter is more than `1 x 1`?

From example below, my problem comes when my `K` matrix has the size of `4 x 4`. When I want to calculate the next `K` by putting `K(2)` the value that come out is only the number from `row:2` and `column:1`, actually I want to refer to matrix `K` completely.

```
 dt = 0.01;
 t=0:dt:10;
 K = zeros(size(t)); %initialize it
 K(1) = 3;%setup initial value 

 for ind=2:length(t)
     K(ind) = K(ind-1)+dt*dK/dt; %where t in your dKdt is subbed by t(ind);
 end

 figure,plot(t,K);
```

The coding above are taken from [this](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/151969-how-to-update-value-of-a-function-at-each-time-step)  link

Comment: `K = K + dt*dK/dt;`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but if you have an NxN matrix and you access it with a single integer (as `K(ind)`), then Matlab starts in the top-left corner of the matrix and counts down the column, then when it gets to the bottom it continues counting from the top of the next column. You can access a specific entry more easily by doing `K(row, column) `.

Comment: I understand that. I dont want to access the matrix **K** by single integer. I want to access the matrix **K** (let say **NxN** matrix) as a whole, to be used in the next operation for every time step

Comment: Are you saying that you want to keep a copy of `K` for every time step? In which case you need 3D array of size NxNxT, where T is your number of time steps. Then access it as `K(:,:,ind)`.

Comment: ...just be careful how many time steps you use though, as this is a great way of filling up memory quickly :)

Comment: Ok got the answer. Do you got any other way for too many time steps? @carthurs

Comment: Just keep fewer `K`s. The extreme is @rayryeng's answer which saves only the current `K`. Or you could subsample with something like `if mod(ind, 10) == 0, K_saved(:,:,nextSaveIndex) = K; nextSaveIndex = nextSaveIndex+1; end` to save every 10 time steps.